# Create JSON file from MongoDB document using Python

Tags: json, mongodb, python-2.7

I am using MongoDB 3.4 and Python 2.7.  I have retrieved a document from the database and I can print it and the structure indicates it is a Python dictionary. I would like to write out the content of this document as a JSON file. When I create a simple dictionary like `d = {"one": 1, "two": 2}` I can then write it to a file using `json.dump(d, open("text.txt", 'w'))`
However, if I replace d in the above code with the the document I retrieve from MongoDB I get the error

> ObjectId is not JSON serializable

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have found out, the issue is that the value of `_id` is in [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

The class definition for `ObjectId` is not understood by the default json encoder to be serialised. You should be getting similar error for ANY Python object that is not understood by the default [JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

One alternative is to write your own custom encoder to serialise `ObjectId`. However, you should avoid inventing the wheel and use the provided [PyMongo/bson](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) utility method [bson.json_util](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html)

For example:

```
from bson import json_util 
import json 

json.dump(json_util.dumps(d), open("text.json", "w"))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that “_id” is actually an object and not natively deserialized.  By replacing the _id with a string as in `mydocument['_id'] ='123` fixed the issue.